# PlayFramework get field from model select

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

Since the play documentation on models is terrible I'll ask here. I have the basic code;

```
public static void Controller() {
        List<Item> item = Item.find("SELECT itemname,id FROM Item WHERE itembool = true ORDER BY itemcreated ASC LIMIT 0,1").fetch();
        
        if ( item == null ) {
            notFound();
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is get the value for 'itemname' returned for the first value returned from an SQL query (The real query is much more complicated and other things so it can't be replaced with methods). I can get the entire first object with `item.get(0)` but I can't figure out how to get the value of 'itemname' as a string and it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

## Edit

Probably should have mentioned in the original question, I need to retrieve by field name, not index. I.E. I can't do `items.get(0)[0];` I need to do `items.get(0)['itemname'];`

Comment: what extra detail do you require? You are trying to run SQL when JPA uses JPQL, it won't work as you want.

Comment: @PereVillega I need to get a field from a select with multiple outputs and refer to it by it's field name, not an index

Comment: please re-read my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation explains this if you read it, [in here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/jpa#FindusingaJPQLquery). Hibernate doesn't use SQL, but JPQL, which has a different syntax as it works with objects, not individual fields.

What you want to do can be achieved in two ways (both in the documentation):

```
List<Item> item = Item.find("SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.itembool = true ORDER BY i.itemcreated ASC").fetch(1);

List<Item> item = Item.find("itembool = true ORDER BY itemcreated ASC").fetch(1);
```

**EDIT:**

On the retrieval part, you will get a list of Item, so you can just access the field directly on the object:

```
item.get(0).getItemName();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Play uses Hibernate under the hood, you need to take a look at [Hibernate's documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select).

In particular, `SELECT itemname,id ...` yields `Object[]` rather than `Item`, so that you can get `itemname` as follows:

```
List<Object[]> items = ...;
String itemname = items.get(0)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you have to do a `select itemname,id ...`, you would not be able to do a `items.get(0)["itemname"]` because as axtavt and Pere have mentioned, you would get a Object[] back. You can instead create another (perhaps immutable) entity class that can be used in this query. Please refer to [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html) for details. You can then model the entity based on your query requirements and use it to fetch information, thus letting hibernate handle all the magic number game for you. That ways, you would have a bean with filled up values that you can use to map back to your model class if you like.

HTH!